# Cast NUMBER to DATE. Error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with a datatype number but I want to convert the column into date. I tried using CAST function but it gives error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER.

For example, 20221203 to 2022-12-03.

Any suggestions?

col_date is the column name

```
select cast(col_date as date)
from school
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as numbers, instead of in the proper data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `to_date()` function:

```
select to_date(col_date, 'YYYYMMDD')
from school
```

That does an implicit conversion from number to string, but you can make it explicit:

```
select to_date(to_char(col_date), 'YYYYMMDD')
from school
```

Of course, it would be better to store your values as proper dates. You may have numbers which don't correspond to actual dates, and will need to decide how to handle those if you do.

---

Oracle's date datatype always has a time component, which will be set to midnight with this conversion. They have no intrinsic human-readable format - your client decides how to display, usually using your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. You can change that with `alter session`, which will affect the display of all date values.

If you want to display the date as a string with a particularly format then you can reverse the process with the `to_char()` function:

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(col_date), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from school
```

If you *only* want it reformatted as a string, and don't need it as a real date at all, you *could* just format the number directly:

```
select to_char(col_date, 'FM0000G00G00', 'nls_numeric_characters='' -''')
from school
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=341bff18036b40e35a7d773344e45c76)

But either way, only do that for final display - leave it as an actual date (not string) for any processing, joins, storage etc.

Comment: it works  but is there any way to remove the timestamp?

Comment: What timestamp? That is a different data type. Are you just talking about seeing the result with the time, like maybe '03-Dec-2022 00:00`?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting int to varchar and then varchar to date

```sql
select cast(cast(col_date as varchar(10)) as date)
```

Comment: it gives error SQL Error [1861] [22008]: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).